# How to return object from function

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a big problem that I can not understand when I take data from Excel sheet.
I use this function to read data (1 row) from excel and it does so correctly

```
function ExtractExcelRows {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param($ExcelFile)

    # Excel.exe not autokill fix
    $before = Get-Process | % { $_.Id }
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelId = Get-Process excel | % { $_.Id } | ? { $before -notcontains $_ }

    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile.FullName)
    $sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $excel.Visible = $false

    $rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count

    # Declare the starting positions
    $rowEmail, $colEmail = 1, 11

    $Rows = @()
    for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++) {
        if ($sheet.Cells.Item($rowEmail+$i, $colEmail).Text) {
            $Rows += @{
                Email = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowEmail+$i, $colEmail).Text
            }
        }
    }

    $workbook.Close($false)
    $excel.Quit()

    Stop-Process -Id $excelId -Force

    Write-Host $Rows.Count  # count 1 row ! right!

    return $Rows
}
```

When I try to save my object in a global variable the result of the count is different and I do not understand why.

```
$global:ExcelData = ExtractExcelRows $ExcelFile
write-host $ExcelData.Count  # count 4 row!!!! not right!
```

Can anyone tell me where the error is and how to fix it?

Comment: You don't need the `$excelId` and `Stop-Process` stuff. Just release the Com objects from memory right after `$excel.Quit()` like this: `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)    | Out-Null; [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null; [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)    | Out-Null; [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: Also, as you are returning an array, use `return ,$rows`. The comma here used as unary operator wraps the array in another single element array. Powershell `unboxes` that to return an array, even if it is empty.

Comment: @Theo -  return ,$rows resolve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put my comments as answer:

```
function ExtractExcelRows {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param($ExcelFile)

    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible = $false

    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile.FullName)
    $sheet    = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $rowMax   = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count

    # Declare the starting positions
    $rowEmail, $colEmail = 1, 11

    $Rows = for ($i = 1; $i -lt $rowMax; $i++) {
        if ($sheet.Cells.Item($rowEmail + $i, $colEmail).Text) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{ 'Email' = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowEmail+$i, $colEmail).Text }
        }
    }

    $workbook.Close($false)
    $excel.Quit()
    # clean up used COM objects
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)    | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)    | Out-Null
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    Write-Host $Rows.Count  # count 1 row ! right!

    # The comma used as unary operator wraps the array in another single element array. 
    # Powershell unboxes that to return an array, even if it is empty.
    return ,$Rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the contents of that variable? I'm betting the first three items are True/False, or something like that. The reason is that the Excel com object's methods tend to return a value to indicate if the execution was successful or not, and all output that is not explicitly redirected is output by the function, not only the items you specify with `return` (for that matter, there is no need to use `return`). You should pipe things like `$workbook.close($false)` to `Out-Null` as such:

```
$workbook.close($false) | Out-Null
$excel.quit() | Out-Null
```

That should account for 2 of your 4 items, I'm not sure what the other one is.